# Airflow Task Priority

Tags: airflow

I have 6 tasks (t1,t2,t3,t4,t5 and t6) all running at same time.

These task is running as t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> t4 >> t5 >> t6

At some point t3 is having issues then t4 is not executed or any of the task is having issues then the later task is not getting executed.

Can some please let me know how can I avoid this problem. I do not want other task to be waiting for earlier task to finish. If the earlier task is not finish within 5 minutes then it should skip.

Comment: does t4 need to run after t3? You don't have to set an upstream task, you can just make it run parallel to tasks t1,t2,t3

Answer (score 0):

The way you've wired your workflow doesn't suit your requirements.

- Tasks that don't really depend on one another shouldn't be wired together. I've seen some people do it just to limit load on external system; but for such use-case, one must employ [`Pools`](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=pool)
- If you want a task to timeout after a given interval (so that downstream tasks can continue), you can exploit the [`execution_timeout`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L186) argument of `BaseOperator`